# How does the CCP insure fair ethnic representation within the CCP?

Tags: china, minorities, chinese-communist-party

How does the CCP insure fair ethnic representation within the CCP?

> Representation at the Party Congress itself will not mean much in
> terms of actual authority. It remains to be seen how many and which
> Tibetans find a place in the Central Committee, one of the three top
> decision-making bodies in China’s political system. **The Politburo is
> the second, and its Standing Committee is the most powerful. To date,
> no Tibetan has found a place in either of these two higher levels of
> party leadership**, despite China illegally occupying Tibet for over 60
> years.

https://savetibet.org/38-tibetan-delegates-at-chinas-20th-party-congress/

Reading the article, it seems there's not much effort made to increase the representation of Chinese minority groups within the CCP, and I couldn't find anything on the Internet that suggests otherwise, but maybe I am wrong. I know there's affirmative action in hiring, education and family planning, but not in the hiring of government officials.

Comment: Landmass is meaningless when trying to determine representees, what you care about is total population. From what I can see there are only 6.3 million Tibetan's in China while there is over 1.4 billion people people. that works out to under 0.5% of the population and you show them as having 1.5% representation which is over what the calculations show they should have. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_people

Comment: I see your question has been edited but is it really surprising that a group that represents under 0.5% of the population might not be represented at the very top of the country in a group of 24 people where party membership and history are among the most critical requirements for getting picked?

Comment: Why would you even assume that the CCP wants to ensure fair ethnic representation?  I don't know one way or the other, but the most obvious answer to "why isn't there more" is "no one cares".  If that's contrary to their _stated_ goal, then it's a meaningful question.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what "fair" means in the title. Is race supposed to be a determining factor in determining political posts? Why not just hire people who are actually aligned with your party's ideology?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways that ethnic minorities receive preferential treatment for government positions:

- A certain proportion of seats in the Chinese People's Political Consultative Committee are allocated to representatives of ethnic minority groups.
- The five Autonomous Regions (Guangxi, Inner Mongolia, Ningxia, Tibet and Xinjiang) tend to have many members of their corresponding ethnic minority, in senior positions of the provincial government. This is despite the fact that only in Tibet does the ethnic minority actually consist of a majority of the population. These provincial posts offer a gateway to roles at the national level. Of course, this doesn't do so much for those minorities which don't have a designated region.